# How to Fractionalize NFT's (high level)

Tags: nft, erc-1155

I have a question to the solidity experts out there. I am Looking into fractionalize NFT's. I was thinking of many different ways of doing it. My first thought was to make a erc-20 market representing the NFT, and having maybe  features like bonding these to a curve to give the tokens liquidity.

However, I am currently reading about erc-1155 as-well and don't have any experience with it. With my surface level understanding and just reading some docs I can create the erc-20 and the erc-721 in the same contract and go about it from there. any thoughts?

So long question short how would you think about this problem of creating shares of an NFT's in a high level?

Comment: Just as an FYI, by doing that you are issuing securities, depending on where you live this ranges from not ok to see you in jail, including liabilities towards anyone who obtains a fractional token. The LPs in a typical scenario would be on the hook as well.

Answer (score 3):

You got the answer yourself: [ERC1155](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc1155) gives you the combination of fungible and non-fungible tokens within the same standard contract.

In essence, you still have a non-fungible token with its ID, like ERC721, but you can mint tokens for such NFT with fungible tokens, like ERC20.

A typical use-case for this standard could be game cards: you have a card called 'weapon X', and you issue 100 copies of that card.

Comment: Thank you for your input and link. Hope you have a good one.