# The simplest way to tokenise NFT into 1 million pieces?

Tags: nft

Does exactly what says on the tin.

I have an NFT that has "million" in the name and I would like to offer 1 million pieces.

Comment: Similar question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/95222/how-to-fractionalize-nfts-high-level

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question. You can do whatever you want.

It's like asking, "How to create an NFT collection of 1 million items?" in the first place. Well, depends on what you want to create.

Does each piece have to make sense in itself (any restrictions?) - or can it just be a set of pixels?

For example, each piece could be the entire NFT but with a single pixel modified according to some formula. Or a chunk of pixels. Etc.

Or it could be a literal carve out of the image, assuming you have >= a million pixels.

Or you could sample pixels from the image randomly so that no sample is the same (which would then work even if you have <a million pixels).

You could also apply a hue or some other transformation which itself becomes the hash that represents the piece.

There are a ton of other options here (really endless).

Any guidelines/restrictions would help narrow this down.

Comment: I will think about deeper. First thoughts: just ERC20 it.

Comment: Yes, you can use ERC1155 as well. So that the NFT still is unique in that only one *type* of it exists, but you can issue multiple repeated copies of it to multiple people (like indeed ERC20): https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155

Comment: ERC1155 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a DAO with a treasury multisig wallet
- Send the NFT to this wallet that now controls the NFT
- DAO mints 1M tokens
- Distribute these tokens to 1M participants

Comment: That's definitely an option but definitely not the simplest :)

Comment: It is the simplest. You do not need to write any code.

Comment: Trying to explain to the user how it works = complicated.

Comment: Complex things need complex solutions

Comment: Sure, maybe, potentially, it depends. How complex is that? `split NFT into pieces` - it's not even a full sentence, it's just **FOUR** words. Complicated and complex start above 2 sentences. Rule of thumb: *"if you can explain it in 2 sentences that's simple"*